# Word Association GRID

Tags: riddle, wordplay

This word association riddle is inspired by the popular Word Association games like Chain Reaction.

Here though is a GRID of words, in 3 columns (1 to 3) and 5 rows (4 to 8). Words in columns are connected to the previous column word (column 2 words are associated with column 1 words in the same row and column 3 words are associated with column 2 words in the same row). Similarly row 2 words are associated with the row 1 words in the same column, row 3 words are associated in the row 2 words in the same column and so on. So the word grid has a horizontal -> and vertical downward association.

The 2 associated words can be 2 separate words or can be combined for 1 word. For example, the 2 words can be First and Born which results into First-born.

The words in column 1 start with those letters.

The words in column 2 end with those letters.

The words in column 3 alternatively end and start with those letters.

These are not complicated words so to make it challenging I have not disclosed any starting or ending words.

[image]

One clue: The last word (row 8 column 3) is a 4 letter word which can also be connected to the first word in column 1 row 4.
Please let me know if more info is needed.

Hint

> First word (1,4) is indeed Good
>
> Last word in the same column is Drugs

Comment: Is the only valid kind of association the sort where you can put the two words together to make either another word or a "standard" phrase? (As opposed to, synonymy or rhyming or being anagrams or whatever.)

Comment: Assuming the answer to the question I asked above is yes, are the pairs always the right way around? E.g., is it definitely g____ n____ that's a thing rather than n____ g____ ?

Comment: Like I said First and Born can be the associated words but you can also have commonly heard phrases like Born Free and 2 words going together like Banana Split.

Comment: Yup. So, always a phrase or single word. And do they have to be the right way around? (I have plausible conjectures for part of the grid that *do* have them always the right way around, so I guess the answer is yes. Not that I'm in any way confident about any of those conjectures.)

Comment: There isn't a no-computers tag; how do you feel about things like searching wordlists for words of the form "first<any letters>n"? In the absence of other opinions I'm going to assume it's better not to do that :-).

Comment: Yes to the first question

Comment: I am not sure how much help you will get from computer. Literally hundreds of words ending with n for exaample. I am not a good programmer so if you can code this in a certain way, may be possible. But that is not fun is it?

Comment: For the last word (row 8 column 3)  to first word (column 1 row 4) connection, is it `___n g___` or is it `g___ ___n` ?

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar Just to be explicit, are you *deliberately* not answering the question about whether the pairs have to be the right way around? Because I've explicitly asked it twice and you seem to be avoiding giving an answer.

Comment: (or did "the first question" mean "the first question I haven't answered yet", in which case maybe that was the answer and I apologize for suggesting you hadn't answered)

Comment: Sorry. Pairs are only one way. Column 1 to 2 then 2 to  3. And then downwards like the game Chain Reaction

Comment: Rubio It is G____ to ____n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of @Sconibulus' answer, with additional feedback from @Sensoray and the hint from above (thanks everyone!!) I think it might be

> ```
> Good   Day     Dream
> Night  Light   House
> Game   Show    Boat
> On     Time    Travel
> Drugs  Testing Plan
> ```

Are any of these correct/which words are deficient?

Comment: Most of them El-Guest, What else goes with Travel that ends in a n? So my  answer only differs from yours at (2,8) and (3,8)

Comment: Is Sconibulus' (3,8) correct? I like their fit better than mine, @DEEM

Comment: Yes it is but not 2,8

Comment: @DEEM Based on your comments below and above I have revised my answer. I'm okay with time testing largely because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_testing) and with testing plan as you've mentioned below because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_plan). Were these two things what you were thinking of?

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer**

I don't have time to finish this, but feel free to use any of it in your own answer:

> Good    ???       Farm? 
> Night   Light   House 
> Guard Snow  Cat 
> Old     Pine    Tree 
> Dog     Tag     ???

Some of these are backwards (that is, should be read bottom-to-top or right-to-left):

> Old Guard and Snow Guard

In addition, some of the more obscure connections:

> [Old Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3rd_U.S._Infantry_Regiment_(The_Old_Guard)) - old US army regiment 
> Cat Tree - one of those structures for house cats to sleep in 
>  [Pine Tag](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pine%20tag) - term for dried pine needles 
>  Old Pine - song by Ben Howard

Comment: Good day, day light and dream house fits

Comment: Day dream as well

Comment: Some but not all of that matches with the partial grid I've been fiddling with...

Answer (score 1):

I am probably way of, just thought it would be fun if

> this "Word association GRID" started with the word grid

EDIT: Removed minispoiler

> Grid       | Electricty     | Steam
>  Network    | Heat           | Humid
>  Graph      | Flow           | Sweat
>  Orthogonal | Commute        | Transport
>  Direction  | Outgoing       | Span

Comment: Hello! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**. Nice answer, but unfortunately, the hint does not agree... though this can serve an alternative! Since you are new, I strongly suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and check out these three sections: *Asking* (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)), *Answering* (not fully necessary, as I see you already know enough on how to construct a sufficient answer) and *Our model* (e.g. [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/conduct)). Glad you joined! Happy puzzling :D

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no rules other than 'words next to each other must create a phrase or a compound word' I feel like there are hundreds of possibilities that could fit, unless I'm missing something like "no adjectives" or "no really random and obscure references like the name of a book". To add difficulty I  continued the trend across columns, so row1col3 wraps to row1col1. No repetition and no word-reversal (pie house vs. house pie) with the exception of the required word-reversal linking the beginning and end. Here's my take on it with some re-used words from other comments & answers.

```
Good       day     dream 
Night      light   House
Ghost      show    talent
Obsessed   love    Tap
Dog        tag     town
```

The phrases / words (linked to their meaning/relevance):

> [good-day](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20day), [daydream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daydream), [dream night](https://www.saczoo.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Dream-Night-Sponsorship.pdf)
>  [night-light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightlight), [lighthouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighthouse), [house ghost](https://northcarolinaghosts.com/piedmont/mordecai-house-ghost/)
>  [ghost show](https://www.ranker.com/crowdranked-list/greatest-paranormal-reality-show-of-all-time), [show talent](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/show%20talent), [talent-obsessed](https://www.vistage.com/research-center/leadership/talent-obsession-key-great-leadership/)
>  obsessed love, [love tap](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lovetap), [tap-dog](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tap-Dog)
>  [dogtag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_tag), [tagtown](https://shop.bombingscience.com/tag-town.html), good town

With the only required and reversed wrap-around giving you:

> good town

Comment: I think you missed a requirement, it says the words have to be associated vertically as well. "Similarly row 2 words are associated with the row 1 words in the same column"

Comment: I knew I was missing something! Thank you :) @Sensoray

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best guess so far, I don't love the last word in column 2, but everything else seems somewhat solid.

> ```
> Good  Day     Dream
> Night Light   House
> Game  Show    Boat
> One   Time    Travel
> Dog   Swing   Plan
> ```

Comment: I think yours is really good. Perhaps rot13(tnzr ba & ba gvzr, vafgrnq bs bar)

Answer (score 1):

As you all but accepted El-Guest's answer, is it:

> Good, Day, Dream
>  Night, Light, House
>  Game, Show, Boat
>  Outer, Space, Travel
>  Drugs, Ring, Man

But then again I can't count! Or read!

So, using the up-down rule, and the error is with ring, is it:

> Good, Day, Dream
>  Night, Light, House
>  Game, Show, Boat
>  On, Time, Travel
>  Drugs, Big, Plan

Comment: Ah dang I had the same idea for the first two lines... eh well, (+1) :D (to which I am surprised I didn't see [@El-Guest's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51366/word-association-grid/70456#70456) before...)) before).. however, it is *very* similar to [@Sconibulus' answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51366/word-association-grid/70450#70450)...

Comment: @JonMark Perry  Wouldn't Drugs Testing and Testing Plan work better?

Comment: @DEEM; well it's your question, you tell me! I don't see Time Testing as a well-known phrase, or Testing Plan for that matter. Test might have worked, but it ends in T.